# Connect QListWidgetItem in setupUI

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to drag &drop a file to a `listwidget` and when `itemactivated`, `plaintextedit` opens and `readAll` lines in file. But returned with error: `"connect() failed between itemActivated(QListWidgetItem*) and read_txt()"`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(873, 663)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.listWidget = listWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 330, 256, 192))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")

        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 200, 104, 87))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")

        self.listWidget.itemActivated.connect(self.read_txt)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QListWidgetItem*")
    def read_txt(self,links):

        file = QtCore.QFile(links.text())
        if file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text):
            self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(file.readAll().data().decode())            
class listWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)   
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):

        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:

            event.acceptProposedAction()
        else:
            event.ignore() 

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            event.acceptProposedAction()
        else:
            event.ignore()
    def dropEvent(self, event):

        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)

            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                links=QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(url.toLocalFile())

            self.addItem(links)
            event.acceptProposedAction()   


if __name__ == "__main__":


    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() 



    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Drag and drop works fine but could not connect `QListWidgetItem` with `readtxt` method in `setupUi`. What is the problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `@pyqtSlot` decorator can only be used in a class that inherits from `QObject`. You can connect signals to any callable object so the easiest way is to just omit the decorator, but if you do need it for one reason or another, you could subclass `QMainWindow` and define the slot in there, e.g.

```
class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.listWidget.itemActivated.connect(self.read_txt)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QListWidgetItem*")
    def read_txt(self, links):
        file = QtCore.QFile(links.text())
        if file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text):
            self.ui.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(file.readAll().data().decode())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    mainWindow = MyMainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    ...
```

Comment: Defining slot in the `Mainwindow` worked but when I defined it in `Ui_MainWindow` like in my question and removed the decorator, still can not `readAll`. I did not fully understand the difference between defining slot under  `Mainwindow` vs `Ui_MainWindow`.

Comment: @scorp Only QObjects like widgets (QWidget, QDialog, QMainWindow, etc) support pyqtSlot since they use the QMetaObject. You should read https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code and https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html